# [closed ]"Operation invalid at this time" raised *randomly* when insterting values in a db2 table

Tags: python, sql, db2, websphere, ibm-cloud

When trying to upload data to an IBM DB2 table (using ibm_db connector for Python 3.7), I'm getting the following error:

**Exception: 
Error 1: [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0126E  Operation invalid at this time. SQLSTATE=HY011 SQLCODE=-99999**

when executing the following part of code:

```
connection=ibm_db.pconnect(*CONNECTION_INFORMATION*)

def execute_many(expr, data):
    stmt = ibm_db.prepare(connection, expr)
    return ibm_db.execute_many(stmt, data)

insert_o_command = "INSERT INTO "+ o_name +" (position_id, title, type, quantity, price_btc, city, country) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

execute_many(insert_o_command, tuple(offers))
```

Where len(offers)==151829

The table schema is:

```
(offer_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,\
        position_id int NOT NULL,\
        title VARCHAR(2047) NOT NULL,\
        type VARCHAR(256),\
        quantity decimal(10, 3) NOT NULL,\
        price_btc decimal(10, 8) NOT NULL,\
        city VARCHAR(2047),\
        country VARCHAR(255))
```

When uploading without slices the last uploaded row is 2109:

```
(133334, 'Борисов (Минская обл., Беларусь)', '', 1.1, 0.01119306, 'Борисов',  'Belarus')
```

The next element in offers has the following values and is not uploaded:

```
(78738, 'Полоцк (Беларусь)', '', 1.1, 0.00784071, 'Полоцк', 'Belarus')
```

In other parts of the script when uploading other data everything works. After the error is raised, the number of rows uploaded to the cloud depends on how (and if) I sliced offers. If I'm uploading everything, it always stucks at the same row. But if I slightly slice the offers list (like, offers[10:]), it will stop and raise the error on a different row. I have checked integrity of data, the rows where uploading stops aren't in any way special.

If I execute uploading in parts (i.e. of 500 rows), a bigger part of these portions are uploaded without interruptions, and 5-7 portions of 500 are uploaded with the errors raised.

Elements on which the error is raised are the same throughout runs, but change when slicing the offers list.

I found no information about this problem on the internet. **For me it looks completely random!**

I am using the IBM Cloud DB2 service (https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/db2)

The symptom repeats if I don't use a connection-pool (i.e. ibm_db.connect instead of ibm_db.pconnect).

**UPD: Now it only uploads 1 row, then stops.**

Comment: Why do you have *different* tables?  All offers should go in *one* table.

Comment: The table schema is: (offer_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,\
        position_id int NOT NULL,\
        title VARCHAR(2047) NOT NULL,\
        type VARCHAR(256),\
        quantity decimal(10, 3) NOT NULL,\
        price_btc decimal(10, 8) NOT NULL,\
        city VARCHAR(2047),\
        country VARCHAR(255))

The last uploaded row is (133334,
 'Борисов (Минская обл., Беларусь)',
 '',
 1.1,
 0.01119306,
 'Борисов',
 'Belarus')

Comment: All offers are uploaded into the o_name table.

python object named offers is a tuple of tuples (tuple of rows).

Comment: @mao I am using the Db2-xo service at IBM Cloud. Do you think I have CLI tracing available there? I haven't found any info on that.

Comment: @mao I have submitted the issue here: https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/495

Thank you.

Comment: @mao the python app is running locally.

cd clidriver install path
cd adm
db2trc on -f trc.dmp
run your application
db2trc off
db2trc flw trc.dmp trc.flw
db2trc fmt trc.dmp trc.fmt
db2trc fmt -c trc.dmp trc.fmtc
db2trc fmt -cli trc.dmp trc.cli

This is what I was asked to perform on github. I am not sure how to find the driver install path.

Comment: @mao thank you!

I have found the path. I have uploaded the traces here: https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/files/4429217/traces.zip

Comment: @mao here are the new traces: https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/files/4441302/traces.zip

Last time I run the app not in the command line together with the tracing commands.

Comment: @mao this time only 1 row was inserted.

I think I did something wrong and when I repeated the procedure I got a trace file of 3 GB. I couldn't even open it with Notepad :)

I think we should close this issue. Obviously I have no capacity to contribute to solving this is it is a bug. I have moved to MySQL and managed to implement my script there.

If there is a bug in DB2 or imb_db connector, I hope it will be fixed. But taking into account my experience in programming, probably there was rather something wrong with my code.

Thanks for help Mao!

Comment: @mao the offers tuple is built from a set. The set is build from a parsed .csv file, which is built by parsing Hydra darknet platform. My script only uploads one row and then throws the error.

Comment: @mao https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Uq1h4wO33XHlIFq_UJKacG17rSFUe-pH (I even left the credentials there)

Comment: @PiotrMarkiełaŭ  ibm_db is hiding the real error by showing CLI0126E. The real error is CLI011E , because your CREATE TABLE needs the decimal columns to be `decimal(31,8)` to suit your data. I will check ibm_db to see what's wrong. But you have an easy workaround.

Comment: Thanks @mao, indeed that was the reason. Should I re-open the issue at github?